# Schur multiplier of $C_{2^n-1} \rtimes C_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

I am interested in computing the Schur multiplier of $C_{2^n-1} \rtimes C_n$ for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where the action of $C_n$ is given as the automorphism of the Singer cycle $C_{2^n-1} \leq \operatorname{GL}_n(2)$ (so, in particular, this action is faithful).

I actually conjecture it is trivial for every $n$, and I have checked small examples I was able to build in GAP.

I was wondering if there is any general result that I am not aware of that could be applied in this case. If I am not mistaken, each group I am considering is a metacyclic group, which I have seen described as an "easy case" for calculating Schur multiplier. Nevertheless, so far I only found results when the two cyclic groups are coprime, an hypothesis which clearly does not hold in general here (for instance $n=6$ has $C_{63} \rtimes C_3$).

Comment: What do you mean? The Singer cycle action would be on $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$, not on $C_n$. Smallest meaningful example would be the group $(C_2)^3 \rtimes (C_7 \rtimes C_3)$ (but I only care about the Schur mult. of the "odd" part if it makes sense)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't delete my earlier answer, but here is a much simpler proof that your groups have trivial Schur Multiplier. This follows from the fact that they have balanced $2$-generator $2$-relator presentations $$\langle x,y \mid yxy^{-1}=x^2,y^n=1 \rangle.$$
Note that the two relations in this presentation imply $x = y^nxy^{-n} = x^{2^n}$, so $x^{2^n-1} = 1$, and hence the presentation defines your semidirect product $C_{2^n-1} \rtimes C_n$.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to check if there was some kind of general fact that applies to my groups before trying to prove it directly - you actually did both! This follows from the Schur multiplier being generated by at most "R-G" elements (R=relations, G=generators), right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be careful because the result that the Schur Multiplier is generated by at most $R-G$ elements applies only to finite groups - the statement is more complicated for infinite groups. IIRC, the converse is known to be false (for finite groups), but it is still an open conjecture whether every finite $p$-group with trivial multiplier has a balanced presentation. The paper by Beyl proves that is true for metacyclic $p$-groups.

Comment: I suspect that the "metacyclic groups are an easy case" statement I cited is precisely because of that paper, and that I misunderstood the context. Anyway, as far as finite groups are concerned (which is the only thing I need to look at) I'm happy there is an easy general answer.
And yes it looks like the converse is false due to Swan, according to an old answer of yours I found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90508/results-in-the-presentation-of-finite-groups). Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right in saying that these groups always have trivial Svchur Multiplier. Here is a very brief sketch of how I think this can be proved.

The metacyclic $p$-groups with trivial Schur Multiplier are listed in Section 5 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-040-02/S0002-9939-1973-0325759-7/S0002-9939-1973-0325759-7.pdf) by F. Rudolf Beyl.

I think, in the case when there is a prime $p$ dividing both $2^n-1$ and $n$, the Sylow $p$-subgroups of your semidirect product have the structure defined in groups of type I on that list, i.e. $G(p^a,p^b,p^{a-b}+1,0)$ with $p$ odd. (I have changed $m,n$ in the paper to $a,b$ to avoid clashing with your $n$.) So the Sylow $p$-subgroups have trivial Schur Multiplier and hence so does the whole group.

To see this, suppose that $n = p^bq$ where $p \not\vert q$.Then to get $p|2^n-1$, we must have $p|2^q-1$, and if $p^c$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $2^q-1$, then the highest power dividing $2^n-1$ is $p^{c+b}$.

So a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $C_{2^n-1} \rtimes C_n$ is of the form $A \rtimes B$, where $A$ and $B$ are cyclic of orders $m := c+b$ and $n$, respectively. It can be seen that the centralizer in $A$ of $B$ has order $2^c$, which means that we do indeed have the group of type I, which is defined by the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^{p^m}=y^{p^n}=1, yxy^{-1} = x^{p^c+1} \rangle$.